# Removing duplicities from Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

```
      // removing duplicities from Dictionary
        var removables = data.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1)).ToList();
        foreach (var key in removables)
            data.Remove(key);
```

This code works pretty well with below input(data):

```
102030;"http://xxx.yyy.com/102030.ashx"
102030;"http://xxx.yyy.com/102030_x.ashx"
```

`102030;"http://xxx.yyy.com/102030_x.ashx"` is removed.

But when I give this input:

```
102030;"http://xxx.yyy.com/102030_x.ashx"
102030;"http://xxx.yyy.com/102030.ashx"
```

`102030;"http://xxx.yyy.com/102030.ashx"` is removed. 
But I only need to remove items containing '_'.

How to solve this problem ? Is it possible to sort inputs by length or adjusting the linq query ?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that you will always have only 2 duplicated values and only one with underscore? What about if you have 3 or more duplications and 2 or more of them have underscores or this scenario is impossible?

Comment: You should really be filtering based on an actual filter instead of guessing which index to skip. Are your inputs strings or something else?

Comment: what's the exact criteria to filter out the urls, skip all those with underscore?

Comment: Maybe your arguments in ToLookUp is in wrong order? [ToLookUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549211(v=vs.110).aspx). Try `data.ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want skip elements with underscores you shouldn't skip first element but remain all elements without underscores:

```
// smart removing duplicities from Dictionary
var removables = data.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key)
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => !y.Key.Contains('_')).ToList();
foreach (var key in removables)
    data.Remove(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

If Mark Shevchenkos answer doesn't float your boat for whatever reason, you can very well sort by length, if you want to.

I've created a dummy data source of type `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` since a Dictionary doesn't allow for duplicate keys.

Removing the duplicates then is straight forward:

1. Group by Key
2. Order by Value length
3. Take the first result of every groupset

   ```
   var source = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>() {
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102030, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102030.ashx"),
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102030, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102030_x.ashx"),
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102040, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102040_x.ashx"),
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102040, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102040.ashx"),
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102050, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102050.ashx"),
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102050, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102050_x.ashx"),
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102060, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102060_y.ashx"),
   new KeyValuePair<int,string>(102060, "http://xxx.yyy.com/102060.ashx")
   ```

   };

   ```
   source.GroupBy (s => s.Key)
         .Select(x => x.OrderBy (y => y.Value.Length))
         .Select (x => x.First())
         .Dump();
   ```

   - [LinqPad Demo](http://share.linqpad.net/4gc6uk.linq)
   - [CSharpPad Demo](http://csharppad.com/gist/447f10563293385719d7)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your solutions.

I find the next:

```
        var removables = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key).SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1)).ToList();
        foreach (var key in removables)
            dict.Remove(key);
```

I only add ordering by Key and now I have correctly ordered set :-)

Thank you for your comments to this solution.